# Radio button click Drop down value change same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have four radio button in task my radio button Looks like   my radio button four value looks like

```
 Conv

 FHA

 VA

 USDA
```

i also have  drop down four value same  as drop down if user select Conv  at time drop down value also change

My jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/cao26pjv/

how i can select drop down based on radio button select

Comment: pls have a look at the following example http://jsfiddle.net/6svcD/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cao26pjv/1/ you can simply adjust this for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input:radio").click(function() {

  var k = $(this).val();

  $('#ddlCompare1').val(k);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
  <label id="lblFHA" style="float:left">
    <input id="loantype" type="radio" value="jumbo" name="loantype" onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()" />&nbsp Conv.</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
  <label id="Label4" style="float:left">

    <input id="radio" type="radio" value="fha" name="loantype" checked onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()" />&nbsp FHA</label>
</div>


<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
  <label id="va" style="float:left">

    <input id="radio" type="radio" value="va" name="loantype" onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()" />&nbsp VA</label>
</div>


<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
  <label id="Label5" style="float:left">

    <input id="radio" type="radio" value="usda" name="loantype" onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()" />&nbsp USDA</label>

</div>



<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
  <select id="ddlCompare1" class="dropdown" onChange="javascript:CompareLoantype(true);">
    <option value="jumbo">Conv</option>
    <option selected value="fha">FHA</option>
    <option value="va">VA</option>
    <option value="usda">USDA</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change event like so:

```
$(':radio').on('change', function() {
    $('#ddlCompare1').val( this.value );
})
.filter(':checked').change();
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/cao26pjv/3/)